# Is a screen reader still able to read encrypted email value?

Tags: html, web-scraping, encryption, screen-readers

We need to protect ourselves from web scraping but at the same time are concerned about impacting accessibility by using encryption to prevent said scraping.

```html
<my-email data-user="myName" data-domain="myEmailDomain"></my-email>
```

```css
my-email::before {
     content: attr(data-user) "@"; } 
my-email::after {
     content: attr(data-domain); }
```

Can a screen reader read encrypted contents?

http://codepen.io/matoeil/pen/EmYypP

Comment: If a screen reader can read it so can bots.

Comment: Why can't you just have some sort of authentication?

Comment: @Artjom B. the intention here is that spambots may read it but not considering it as e-mails while human being using the reader device understand it is

Answer (score 0):

If you are that bothered by scraping, why even display the full email address?  Is it really a requirement that the email address be shown at all?

Why not obfuscate the address (remove parts of the domain, or some letters of the account).

Comment: the email must be transparently displayed to the end user but protected from bot

Comment: @Matoeil Generate an image of the content. That will prevent scraping, and will transparently display to the end user, but will not be usable by a screen reader.